# Converting syslog to Json - expecting as object

Tags: python, json, regex, lambda, syslog

I have a python lambda code to convert syslog records to Json. when deployed it getting unexpected errors.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import base64
import json
import gzip
import re

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []
    succeeded_record_cnt = 0
    failed_record_cnt = 0

    for record in event['records']:
        print(record['recordId'])
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])

        regex_string = (r"^((?:\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?"
                        r"|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b\s+(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])\s+"
                        r"(?:(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:\.,][0-9]+)?)))) (?:<(?:[0-9]+).(?:[0-9]+)> )"
                        r"?((?:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)) ([\w\._/%-]+)(?:\[((?:[1-9][0-9]*))\])?: (.*)")
        p = re.compile(regex_string)
        m = p.match(payload)
        if m:
            succeeded_record_cnt += 1
            data_field = {
                'timestamp': m.group(1),
                'hostname': m.group(2),
                'program': m.group(3),
                'processid': m.group(4),
                'message': m.group(5)
            }
            output_record = {
                'recordId': record['recordId'],
                'result': 'Ok',
                'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(data_field))
            }
        else:
            print('Parsing failed')
            failed_record_cnt += 1
            output_record = {
                'recordId': record['recordId'],
                'result': 'ProcessingFailed',
                'data': record['data']
            }

        output.append(output_record)

    print('Processing completed.  Successful records {}, Failed records {}.'.format(succeeded_record_cnt, failed_record_cnt))
    return {'records': output}
```

When I deploy this I am getting error like, it is expecting data as an object and I decoded that records and deployed it again but getting similar errors:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/ec2_logs_parquet.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
    m = p.match(payload)
```

I tried to fix that using below patches to decode it and created seperate variable to pass the data but it is not working.

```
    payload = base64.b64decode(record['data'])
    payload_str = payload.decode('utf-8')

    p = re.compile(regex_string)
    m = p.match(payload_str)
```

Still getting error. Did I miss anything here ?

Comment: You surely aren't getting the SAME error.  What is it now?

Comment: And you don't really need a regular expression for this.  Syslog records are strictly formatted.  The timestamp is `payload[:15]`, and you can just use `split` to get the rest.  That will be much more efficient.

Comment: `[ERROR] UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/ec2_logs_parquet.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
    payload2 = payload.decode('utf-8')`   
 Getting this error

Comment: That clearly tells you your lines are not UTF-8.  You'll have to figure out what character set they are.  We can't tell you that.  The fact that it's in the first couple of bytes might mean these aren't really syslog records.  Have you printed `payload` to see what you're actually getting?

Comment: I think looking at the `payload` (as has already been suggested) is the first thing you should do, to understand what type of data you are really receiving. If it doesn't help, you can update your question with the newly gained information. Also, the parser posted by @Tim Roberts works for (default) RFC3164 formatted syslog messages - the same *type* of syslog messages you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much simpler way to parse syslog records.

```
def convert_log( row ):
    time = row[:15]
    host,prog,message = row[16:].split(maxsplit=2)
    if '[' in prog:
        prog,process = prog.split('[')
        process = process[:-2]
    else:
        proc = prog[:-1]
        process = ''

    data_field = {
        'timestamp': time,
        'hostname': host,
        'program': prog,
        'processid': process,
        'message': message
    }
    return data_field

for line in open('/var/log/syslog'):
    print( convert_log( line ))
```

Comment: I am getting event records directly to lambda function. How can i read it from '('/var/log/syslog')'
Can you please suggest how we can convert it by using events

Comment: Do you not see the parallel between my `for row in open` and your `for record in event['records']:`?

Comment: Can you please send one sample syslog conversion

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  That's EXACTLY what my code is.  I've now changed it to separate the conversion of the line from the reading of the line.  Maybe that will help you see how to integrate this.

Comment: your code is not correct. it is not working

Comment: It does work.  I tried it.  If you're having trouble, "it is not working" is not a helpful description.

Comment: can you please post your example implementation code so that it will be very helpful to understand

Comment: What are you talking about?  That IS my implementation code.  You're looking at it.  There's nothing else.